# TypeScript keeps changing "this" reference after transpiling

Tags: typescript

I was trying to run the following code snippet:

```js
interface IPerson{
  firstName:string,
  lastName:string,
  age:number,
  fullName:()=>string
}

var person:IPerson = {    
  firstName: "Tom",
  lastName: "Hal",
  age: 25,    
  fullName: ():string=>{return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName}
}

console.log(person.fullName());
console.log(person.age);
```

What I found is that tsc transpiler is changing this reference and the result for the first console.log statement is undefined, that's because the transpiled code is as follow:

```js
var _this = this;
var person = {
    firstName: "Tom",
    lastName: "Hal",
    age: 25,
    fullName: function () { return _this.firstName + ' ' + _this.lastName; }
};
console.log(person.fullName());
console.log(person.age);
```

**"this"** reference has been changed, how I can prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the arrow function to a regular function

```
function():string {return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName}
```

This is intended behavior, TypeScript does that when targeting ES5-. Because that is exactly the behavior you will get running the code on ES6+.

Another option is to use [method definitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions), you can write it like this

```
fullName(): string { return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName; }
```

Comment: thank you for your quick response, so there's no way to make it run with the code that I mentioned above?

Comment: Not with that exact code. But you can also use this `fullName():string {return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName}` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions